# How to push ASP.NET MVC to GitHub without connection string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, github

I have an application ASP.NET MVC 5 (.NET 4.6.2) developed using Visual Studio and 
I'm using Webhook from Github to deploy my aplication on Azure. 
I've already create the connection string on Azure so I need to push the App on GitHub without connection string (and of course not to publish my password).
There are somehow to remove the connection string automatically when I push the App on GitHub?

Comment: Better than remove it when you push, don't include it in the first place. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=windows

Comment: That's exactly I looking for, works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding it in code, or in an application.config folder, it should be stored either in User Secrets, an Environment Variable (which stores it in plaintext so beware), or something like [Azure Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/)

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=windows for options for storing secrets during development.

Comment: Fixed typo. Thanks @PeterB